# Query From MYSQL Not Outputting In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

my code

```
$query = "SELECT `url` FROM `$drop` WHERE `vidname`= '$tier_two'";
$dave= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<p>";
print $query;
```

im trying to the url feild to echo but im coming up with blanks

Comment: You'd only be printing out the `$query` you wrote? You mean fetching the data?

Comment: yeah i want to output the url sotred in the db

Comment: Do you get the intended query when you print $query

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Where is mysql_fetch_array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM '$drop' WHERE vidname= '$tier_two'");  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    

  $url = $row["url"];   
  echo $url;

}
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @ids That means your query failed and you didn't check `mysql_error`. Also it means you're using the woefully obsolete `mysql_query` interface. You need to upgrade to something more modern like PDO.

Comment: hi i was just using a rough draft PDO is next on my list thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);

echo $url;
```

note: printing `$query` is printing your sql command.., for printing your query result, you can use my suggestion or @Companjo 's suggestion (ah, his post was deleted).. and (as @Phil's comment) the reason to use `mysqli_*` is because `mysql_*` is deprecated..

**reference**:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
you might want to see the connection creation using `mysqli` here (if you decide to use `mysqli_*`):
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

addition: `mysql_` and `mysqli_` don't differ much.. you'll realize it as you trying it..